# Set ObjectChoiceField values from a Database in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How to set values to ObjectChoiceField from Database in BlackBerry?

Comment: In what ways have you tried to solve this yourself?  Include relevant code, and point to the problem you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] days={"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"};
ObjectChoicdField ocf = new ObjectChoiceField("Days.",days,days.length-1) {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        super.paint(g);     
    }
};
ocf.setChangeListener(this);
add(ocf);
```